# How to programatically change the camera exposure on Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile, camera, augmented-reality

I need to change (lower) the camera exposure from inside a program.

The documented API I found (DirectShow) don't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably don't really need the "augmented-reality" tag for this question.

Comment: How do you control the camera? Is there a low-level dll or C functions in the OS that you need to call? Are you using Windows-mobile or WindowsCE. I just want to verify a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You may be setting the exposure property to the wrong value, or your device may simply not support the DirectShow interface.  See this article (which may or may not be relevant to your device):

http://www.quickcamteam.net/documentation/faq/questions-about-accessing-the-exposure-time-through-directshow

The specific device(s) you're using may have an API that you can access instead of using DirectShow.  Which devices are you targeting for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically targeting higher-end Samsung Windows Mobile phones, their Windows Mobile SDK has an advanced camera API that enables you to set ISO speed.  It's available at http://innovator.samsungmobile.com.